# Why Aren't the Styles for Infragistics Ignite UI for Angular List View Working?

Tags: angular, infragistics, ignite-ui, ignite-ui-angular

It looks like the igx-form-group__input--search class requires another stylesheet imported somewhere, but I'm not finding a reference to make it work in like in stackblitz

**Mine**

[image: Screenshot1]
https://github.com/djbreen7/IgniteUISandBox
https://djbreen7.github.io/IgniteUISandBox/

**Infragistics Demo**

[image: Screenshot2]
https://stackblitz.com/angular/pernmgqeavg

I'm sure it's a simple fix. I just can't see what I'm missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like the class names you mean are valid for igniteui-angular 5.2.1 version, while in the version of your Sandbox app (igniteui-angular 5.3.0-rc) those have been changed.

Please note that this latter version introduces Input Group, which makes creating forms even easier:
https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/input-group